# Closure of $C^\infty(\Omega)$ with respect to non-standard norm

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain of $\mathbb R^d$ with smooth boundary $\Gamma$.

I am wondering if it is possible to characterise the closure of $C^{\infty}(\overline\Omega)$ with respect to the norm
$$
\|u \|:=\sqrt{\|u \|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+ \| u\|^2_{L^2(\Gamma)}}.
$$
Any useful reference will be very appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that you're going to get $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$, or if you like, $L^2$ of the disjoint union $\Omega \sqcup \Gamma$.  You can take a smooth function on $\overline{\Omega}$ and modify its values arbitrarily on $\Gamma$ while changing its $L^2(\Omega)$ norm only infinitesimally.

Comment: More precisely, consider the map from $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ with your norm into $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$ defined by $u \mapsto (u|_{\Omega}, u|_{\Gamma})$.  By definition of your norm, it is an isometry, and I think you can show it has dense image.  If so then the completion of $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ in your norm will be isometrically isomorphic to $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$ and $\sigma$ be surface measure on $\Gamma$, both of which may be extended trivially to measures on $\overline{\Omega}$.  Then if $\mu = m + \sigma$ is their sum, your norm is just the $L^2(\overline{\Omega}, \mu)$ norm.  And $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense in $L^2(\overline{\Omega}, \mu)$, e.g. by Stone-Weierstrass; this argument works for any measure.  So the completion is (isometrically isomorphic to) $L^2(\overline{\Omega}, \mu)$, or equivalently, to the direct sum $L^2(\Omega,m) \oplus L^2(\Gamma,\sigma)$.

---

Previous, overcomplicated argument (don't read):

The completion is isometrically isomorphic to the Hilbert direct sum $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$.  If you like, this is equivalent to $L^2(\overline{\Omega})$ where $\overline{\Omega}$ is equipped with the sum of Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$ plus surface measure on $\Gamma$.

Identify $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ with a subspace of $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$ in the obvious way, by identifying $u$ with $(u|_\Omega, u|_\Gamma)$.  Then your norm agrees with the norm of $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$, so it suffices to show that $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$.

Let $J(\Gamma) \subset C(\Gamma)$ be the "jet space" of functions $v : \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ which have a $C^\infty$ extension to some neighborhood of $\Gamma$.  By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $J(\Gamma)$ is dense in $C(\Gamma)$ (with respect to the uniform norm) and therefore dense in $L^2(\Gamma)$ (with respect to the $L^2$ norm).  Also, the space $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ of compactly supported smooth functions is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$.  I'll show that the closure of $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ contains $C^\infty_c(\Omega) \oplus J(\Gamma)$.

Let $u \in C^\infty_c(\Omega), v \in J(\Gamma)$.  Extend $v$ to a smooth function on some neighborhood of $\Gamma$ and multiply by a smooth cutoff to obtain a $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$ function, still called $v$, whose support is disjoint from that of $u$.  Now consider a sequence of smooth cutoff functions $\phi_n : \overline{\Omega} \to [0,1]$ which equal 1 on $\Gamma$ and converge pointwise to 0 on $\Omega$.  The functions $u_n = u + \phi_n v$ are in $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$.  We have $u_n|_\Omega \to u$ pointwise and boundedly, hence in $L^2(\Omega)$, and $u_n|_{\Gamma} = v$ for all $n$.  Hence $u_n \to (u,v)$ in $L^2(\Omega) \oplus L^2(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Dear @NateEdredge, thank you for the answer. I was wondering how your argument extends in the case, instead of $\Gamma$, I consider a subset $\Gamma_S$.

Comment: Then, there is another step that is not very clear to me. How do we know that $J(\Gamma)$ is dense in $C^0(\Gamma)$ w.r.t. the uniform norm? By SW theorem, but why can I apply it?

Comment: @avati91: I think it works exactly the same for $\Gamma_S \subset \Gamma$.  Just replace $\sigma$ by the restriction of the surface measure to $\Gamma_S$.

Comment: @avati91: For the $J(\Gamma)$ argument (which I didn't really like, but no matter): if $f_1, f_2 : \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ have extensions to some $C^\infty$ functions $\bar{f}_1, \bar{f}_2$ defined on neighborhoods $U_1, U_2$ of $\Gamma$ respectively, then $U_1 \cap U_2$ is a neighborhood of $\Gamma$ and $\bar{f}_1 + \bar{f}_2$ is defined on $U_1 \cap U_2$ and is a $C^\infty$ extension of $f_1 + f_2$.  So $J(\Gamma)$ is closed under addition.  You similarly show it is closed under multiplication. [...]

Comment: Got it :-) Thank you very much again!

Comment: @avati91: $J(\Gamma)$ contains the constants because a constant function on $\Gamma$ trivially extends to the same constant function on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$.  And if $x_1, x_2 \in \Gamma$, we can find a $C^\infty$ $\bar{f} : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ which separates them, whose restriction to $\Gamma$ is a function in $J(\Gamma)$ which separates them.  So $J(\Gamma)$ is an algebra which contains the constants and separates points.